# HTML, how to add anchor

Tags: html, anchor

Im fairly new to HTML. I ran my site through SEMRush, I would like to know how to add anchor text to this line of code

`a href="/blogpost/How-to-Remove-Mold-from-Exterior-Walls" class="block-20 rounded"  style="background-image: url('images/How-to-Remove-Mold-from-Exterior-Walls.png');">`

I have tried everything I know, I can make the warning go away but then the picture also vanishes fromwebsite

Comment: is typing `<` in front of `a href` is solution for you?

Comment: What is the end result you want to get? What did you try? Do you want to add that by hand, or through some kind of program? What was that "warning" and how did you make it go away?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/blogpost/How-to-Remove-Mold-from-Exterior-Walls" class="block-20 rounded">
 <div style="background-image: url('images/How-to-Remove-Mold-from-Exterior-Walls.png');">
</a>
```